# How to stop slug generation in OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, slug, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

When I write non-unicode letters in OctoberCMS Rainlab blog title, it's converted to English letters such as this:
موضوع جديد
is converted to: modoaa-gdyd
I don't want this, I want only to replace spaces with hyphen to be for example:
موضوع-جديد
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by editing the following file:

modules\system\assets\ui\storm-min.js

I emptied the following variables:

```
ARABIC_MAP={},PERSIAN_MAP={}
```

and edited the slugify function by replacing this line:

```
slug=slug.replace(/[^-\w\s]/g,'')
```

with this:

```
slug=slug.replace(/[^-\w\sء-ي]/g,'')
```

so, now the slug accepts Arabic characters normally

Answer (score 2):

Hmm for now it seems we are not able to extend `js plugin` for give purpose

but we can extend plugin to not use `slug` type

you can add this code to any of your plugin's `boot` method

> `boot` method is `imp`

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\DemoTest;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerComponents()
    {
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }


    public function boot() {

         \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFieldsBefore', function($widget) {            
            // You should always check to see if you're extending correct model
            if(!$widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Blog\Models\Post) {
                return;
            }

            // now we remove type = slug , and use exact 
            // as type = slug will convert chars ARABIC_MAP to english so
            $widget->fields['slug']['preset']['type'] = 'exact';            
        });         

    }
}
```

> It will not solve your complete problem but it can simply copy your `blog-title` exactly in to slug, in `slug text-box` then you need to add **`/`** at the beginning and then you also need to place **`' ' => '-'`** (dash at spaces) **manually**.

sorry this will not solve your whole issue, but just saves you from copying `title` to slug again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function as a helper in your app and reuse it

```
public static function generateSlug($title)
{
    $title = strtolower($title);

    $title = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", ' ', $title);

    $title = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", '-', $title);

    return $title;
}

$slug = Helpers::generateSlug('موضوع جدید', '-');
//will produce  "موضوع-جدید"
```

Or use this package
[Sluggable Persian](https://github.com/morilog/eluquent-sluggable-persian/)

Comment: Well, but how can I stop octobercms slug auto-generation?